# Why do I and my friend lose our stuff when we leave and rejoin our Minecraft survival world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my friend got into playing a lot of Minecraft recently, and we often leave because we have to do other things, so we leave the game. We have a server without mods, is not in offline mode, and is running 1.14.4.

For some reason, all of our stuff is lost, and we have lost interest in the worlds multiple times. I thought it was just not saving, so we took precautions, and we stood still for a minute so it would save, sometimes it would work.

When it didn't we got pretty mad and I couldn't find a solution and nothing online tells me how to fix it. it hasn't happened before and I've been making servers for me and my friends for 2 years now. If someone could help me with this problem, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Is the server in "offline mode"?

Comment: This might need more details through some specific questions in the comments, but the problem and question seem clear to me.

Comment: Consider inspecting the player data with NBTExplorer. eg if the server is treating you as a new player because of offline mode, you will likely find the old player data there and be able to copy it.

Comment: the server is not in offline mode and it is just a regular vanilla 1.14.4 minecraft server also this is not a lan world.

Comment: Also about NBTExplorer, how do i use it in your own multiplayer world to get other players stuff back?

Comment: I'm assuming you are running a dedicated server on your own computer (if not, please clarify). The world data should be saved in the working directory of the server. Open NBTExplorer and navigate to that folder, and look for playerdata/*.dat files. btw when you lose your items, do you also find yourself back at the spawn point?

Comment: i am running a dedicated server on my computer and for your clarification i do go to spawn when i lose my items

Comment: oh and also about the file of where your inventory is, i was looking there and it says no entries in inventory...